# Is the usage of 'this' correct in this sentence?

Tags: colloquialisms

Is it okay to say 'There was ***this*** mesmerizing, melancholic music everywhere filling the hearts with wonder and awe.'? Is it right to use 'this' in this context or is it considered colloquial usage?

Comment: What are you trying to communicate with that wording?

Comment: There would be less hint of a register clash with 'There was this old geezer sitting in a deckchair smoking a fag', but I don't think your example sounds too bad.

Comment: To clarify: yes, it is generally considered colloquial. I would leave it out, especially as the rest of your sentence is quite literary in tone.

Comment: Thank you so much, Edwin and Kate. That was very helpful.

Comment: *This* is okay, but I'd change *the hearts* to *our hearts* or *everybody's hearts*.

Comment: @Clare simply omitting the article should also work: "filling hearts with wonder" without needed to state that it was everyone. It's a bit more poetic, though.

Answer (score 0):

There seems no problem with the use of 'this' in your sentence. However, even if you don't use it, a little effect will be there. In one sense it adds some specific-ness to the description.

Answer (score 0):

I can't find a definitive source, so this is just a native author's opinion...

"This" in the context provided is colloquial. It's wholly unnecessary for the meaning for the sentence, but you could include it anyway if you're trying to convey a more "personal" dialogue (e.g. recounting a memory).

If you don't want the sentence to have that "conversational" feel, or if the music itself *isn't* the focus of the sentence, I'd agree with the comments and remove it.

e.g.

Ted said, "There was this music everywhere!" *<-- actual dialogue*

I remembered last night. It was dark and there was this music everywhere. *<-- "personal" narrative*

### On a side note:

Using both "this music" and "the hearts" makes your sentence sound like an awkward mix of the personal (e.g. "this" music) and impersonal (e.g. "the" hearts). If that's *not* what you want, then I'd suggest using "**those** hearts" or "**their** hearts".